# Wait for static initializer

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I want to have a static field in a class to be automatically initialized when another class is loaded.

Something like this:

```
class ServiceBase {
    static Object lock = new Object();
    static ServiceBase service;
    static void setService(ServiceBase service) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ServiceBase.service = service;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    void f() throws Exception {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (service == null){
                lock.wait();            
            }
       }
       //use service
   }
}

class ServiceImpl extends ServiceBase {
    static {
        ServiceBase.setService(ne ServiceImpl());
    }
}
```

The problem is that is `f` is called before `ServiceImpl` is loaded, it hangs in a deadlock.

What's the best way of initializing the service instance? (I cannot use Spring or other huge frameworks)

Comment: Do you mean `ServiceBase` instead of `A`? If not, what is `A`?

Comment: How does "implements ServiceBase" work when ServiceBase is a class? What is A?

Comment: It's strange that you setting service to A.service while checking ServiceBase.service in `f()`

Comment: You can always just refer trivially to `ServiceImpl` in `ServiceBase` (e.g. `if (ServiceImpl.class != null);`) to force it to be loaded. However, requiring a subclass to be loaded for the correct functioning of the parent class indicates a design issue, since you should not have cyclical dependencies like that.

Comment: you're right, I messed up the class names

Comment: Do you mean `Service.service = service;`, or should it be `ServiceBase.service = service;`

Comment: I cannot refer to ServiceImpl from ServiceBase, because ServiceBase does not know ServiceImpl

Comment: Do you mean `class ServiceImpl implements ServiceBase`, or should it be `class ServiceImpl implements Service`? Putting correct code would make it an awful lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is overly complex. You should not need to worry about synchronization or any of that.

The most obvious simplification is to pass the `Service` instance as a constructor parameter to `ServiceBase`:

```
class ServiceBase {
  private final Service service;

  ServiceBase(Service service) {
    this.service = checkNotNull(service);
  }

  void f() {
    // service is guaranteed to be present.
  }
}
```

This way, you can never actually call `f()` before a non-null service is available.

If your concern is that you want the same instance of `ServiceImpl` to be used every time, create a `ServiceBaseProvider` class which you use to get instances of `ServiceBase`, instead of constructing them directly:

```
class ServiceBaseProvider {
  private static ServiceImpl INSTANCE = new ServiceImpl();

  static ServiceBase getInstance() {
    return new ServiceBase(INSTANCE);
  }
}
```

Or, of course, inject the same instance of `ServiceBase` wherever it is required, which makes it much easier to (for example) inject a mock instance during tests.

Comment: Your solution of course is elegant... but I can't implement it. The problem is that I need to  refactor a class that has only static fields, so it is never constructed (and I don't know when it's the correct moment to call the constructor).  I can't use sublcassing (beacuse I have static methods), so I need to find a way around it

Comment: @MicheleDaRos you must construct `ServiceBase`, or you can never call `f()`, which is non-static.